# Eureka Server Dashboard not showing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

This is EurekaServerApplication :

```
package dev.nano.eurekaserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and this is the eureka server application.yml :

```
#Server
server:
  port: 8761
#Spring
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka-server
  output:
    ansi:
      enabled: ALWAYS
#Eureka-Server
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    fetch-registry: false
    register-with-eureka: false
```

and heres the eureka server pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>ecomicroservices</artifactId>
        <groupId>dev.nano</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>eureka-server</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

these r the versions im using in the parent module :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.8.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
    <map.struct.version>1.4.2.Final</map.struct.version>
    <spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>3.2.3</spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>
    <lombok.mapstruct.binding.version>0.2.0</lombok.mapstruct.binding.version>
    <spring.boot.dependencies.version>3.2.3</spring.boot.dependencies.version>
    <spring.cloud.dependencies.version>2020.0.3</spring.cloud.dependencies.version>
  </properties>
```

everything seems right but when i run the app i just get a 404 error page, im using jdk 17.

i tried changing the port multiple times, tried private navigator, tried a differrent browser, tried restarting pc.

Comment: what does your parent pom look like? what do your start up logs look like? can you telnet to the server port?

Answer (score 0):

You must add dependencyManagement into your pom file. Add this

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2023.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

This is a pom file that will work for your code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.rmm.submodule</groupId>
    <artifactId>discovery</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>discovery</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2023.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

And this is Main class

```
package org.example;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class , args);
    }

}
```